# Dropbox file unique identifier - RESTful API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Is there any unique identifier associated with a Dropbox file that doesn't change with revisions/changes/renaming, that can be accessed via the RESTful API? I want to store it in the database and keep track of some operations on the file.

Comment: Guys @Dropbox, are you listening?

Comment: Yes, we're tracking this as a feature request, but we don't have any news right now.

Comment: @Greg any news about this?

Comment: No news on this, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, the Dropbox API does not currently expose any sort of file ID or hash like this.

---

Edit: The Dropbox API v2 does now offer file IDs that persist across moves/renames. You can find more information under "Path formats" in [the documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#formats).

The file ID is available as the `id` field on the `FileMetadata` object, e.g., as returned by [/files/get_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata).

Comment: Aw. Another even more sad face :(

Comment: Aw. Yet Another Sad freaking Tsunami face

Comment: Aw. :( Yet another yet another sad face.

Comment: Aw. Saddest face ever :-(

Comment: Aw. Even my cat has sad face now.

Answer (score 4):

The new Dropbox [API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http#documentation-files-get_metadata) supports IDs for files and folders.

However, it doesn't automatically differentiate file/folder moves, renames, etc. from deletions and creations in the event stream. You can use a service like [Kloudless](https://kloudless.com) which provides a unified cloud storage API that includes file/folder IDs for Dropbox. Kloudless also normalizes the [event stream](http://developers.kloudless.com/docs#events) and provides access to several other cloud storage services through a single API. (I work at Kloudless)